# How to Add/Remove Options from Auto-Play Dialog when Inserting a CD/DVD?

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, compact-disc, optical-drive

When I insert a blank CD, it gives me every option except the one I want (burn disc with Nero).  How do I control what appears on this auto-play dialog?  I have Windows XP 64-bit edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[How to Change CD/DVD content AutoPlay actions in Windows XP](http://www.winbookcorp.com/_technote/WBTA20000846.htm)**

[image]

Here you can change the default actions.

If you want to change the CD/DVD burning options, read Doug Knox' guide:

**[Add Your CD Burning Program to AutoPlay Actions](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/add_burner.htm)**

... which happens to deal with Nero Burning ROM (involves editing the registry).

Comment: I don't have Windows 7, Molly.  I don't even have Vista.  Thanks for help, though!  Hey I think you were helping me on another question I am trying to figure out: http://superuser.com/questions/85580/starting-to-burn-cd-and-system-momentarily-freezes

Comment: yep, just spotted that, edite my answer :)

Comment: Yes, I just tried this and it works!  Thank you.  Although it kind of sucks having to edit the registry like that.  Oh well, now I can write up a quick app to automate the process :D

Comment: well, Vista/7 are easier, as they do offer defaults for blank cd/dvd, as you may have seen in the original answer ... is it a reason to upgrade? not in my books, it isn't :)